# How to get 'Last modified' information of parquert files in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've just started to use BigQuery and Looker. So as to be able to know when the information in a external table was updated, I would need to have access to the atribute 'Last modified' from the parquet files.
I have already the _FILE_NAME information and I can't use the metadata from the External table since it doesn't reflect when the information is updated.

This would the info i need to access to:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UinEh.png)

**I have already the _FILE_NAME information and I can't use the metadata from the External table since it doesn't reflect when the information is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible through BigQuery external tables